# Is there a way to compare comma delimited field in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have some data, mapped like this (comma delimited)

```
Name      Items
Andrew    apples, bananas, oranges
Jane      bananas, apples
Mary      oranges, apples
```

I would like to compare the fruits that each name has, so that:

When a user enters two names, I can determine, what is the difference between Andrew's fruits and Jane's fruits. This can be shown in a field where the fruits which aren't present in both sets is listed, and the user which has that (different) fruit is shown.

How can I do this?

Comment: There is, but it will depend on what engine you're using. More importantly though, is that you shouldn't be using a comma-separated list for that column. Put each Item into its own row. What you have is a violation of first normal form, which is the bare minimum for a well designed database schema.

Comment: How do you do that?  You fix your data model so the data is stored in a *normalized* format.  If you use a database properly -- storing only one value in a column -- then such a query would not be a problem.

Comment: If the user gives the names, f.e. `@Name1='Jane'` and `@Name2='Mary'`, then what should the result be? bananas? oranges? bananas & oranges? kiwi?

Answer (score 0):

A solution for MS Sql Server (+2017).
It uses STRING_SPLIT to, yes indeed, split the strings.

Then using an `EXCEPT` it remove the intersecting Items.
Which result in the items that only the first name has.

```
DECLARE @Name1 NVARCHAR(30);
DECLARE @Name2 NVARCHAR(30);

SET @Name1 = 'Mary';
SET @Name2 = 'Jane';

SELECT DISTINCT LTRIM(spl.value) AS Item
FROM TestTable t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.Items, ',') spl
WHERE Name = @Name1
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT LTRIM(spl.value) AS Item
FROM TestTable t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.Items, ',') spl
WHERE Name = @Name2
ORDER BY Item;
```

**When using this sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
  Name NVARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
  Items NVARCHAR(300) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO TestTable (Name, Items) VALUES
('Andrew', 'apples, bananas, oranges'),
('Jane', 'bananas, apples'),
('Mary', 'oranges, apples');
```

**It returns:**

```
Item
--------------
oranges
```

Comment: This doesn't show the name that corresponds to that item though

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, I'm waiting on the OP.  If he wants get the items from the first person that the second person doesn't have? Then it doesn't really matter to get the name in the result. Since you know it's from the first person anyway.  Btw, I wonder if there would actually exist some standard SQL solution that could split strings.